# Read the last row and remove the column based on a condition in R

Tags: r

My data frame looks like this:

```
   Var1   var2
1   1       11
2   2       NA
3   NA      NA
4   4       14
5   NA      NA
6   6       16
7   7       17
8   8       NA
9   9       19
10  10      NA
11   1       0
```

I need to read the last row( arbitrary) of a data frame and if it is 'TRUE', I need to retain that column and if it is 'FALSE' I need to delete that particular column and store the output in a new data frame

For the above example the result should be:

```
   Var1
1   1
2   2
3   NA
4   4
5   NA
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  10
```

2ND column is removed, since the last row reads '0'.

Comment: Really sorry it looks like the data alignment is screwed up..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `as.logical`:

```
> mydf[as.logical(mydf[nrow(mydf), ])]
   Var1
1     1
2     2
3    NA
4     4
5    NA
6     6
7     7
8     8
9     9
10   10
11    1
```

Or `mydf[, as.logical(mydf[nrow(mydf), ]), drop = FALSE]` if you want the same code compatible with matrices too.